# Validate only alphanumeric characters in Laravel

Tags: php, regex, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation

I have the following code in my Laravel 5 app:

```php
public function store(Request $request){
    $this->validate($request, ['filename' => 'regex:[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]']);
}
```

My intentions are to permit filenames with **only alphanumeric characters, dashes and underscores** within them. However, my regex is not working, it fails even on a single letter. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `'regex:/^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*$/'` or just `'regex:/^[\w-]*$/'`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It works! Thanks, but what was my mistake?

Comment: The point is that the whole string should match.

Comment: The mistake, for the record, was a lack of pattern delimiters (`/.../`) and anchors (`^...$`).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to make sure the pattern matches the whole input string. Also, the alphanumeric and an underscore symbols can be matched with `\w`, so the regex itself can be considerably shortened.

I suggest:

```
'regex:/^[\w-]*$/'
```

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `[\w-]*` - zero or more word chars from the `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` range or `-`s
- `$` - end of string.

**Why is it better than `'alpha_dash'`**: you can further customize this pattern.

Comment: Thank you, this is the most complete answer of all even with `alpha_dash` mentioned!

Answer (score 11):

use laravel rule,

```
    public function store(Request $request){
    $this->validate($request, ['filename' => 'alpha_dash']);
}
```

[Laravel validation rule for alpha numeric,dashes and undescore](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#rule-alpha-dash)

Comment: Thanks! it's actually `alpha_dash`

Comment: sorry, i have linked the correct one, but added the wrong one, anyway I modified the code above..

Answer (score 8):

Might be easiest to use the built in alpha-numeric validation:

```
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#rule-alpha-num

$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'filename' => 'alpha_num',
]);
```

Comment: Thanks! it's actually `alpha_dash`

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to quantify the regex, it also wasn't quite properly formed.

```
public function store(Request $request){
    $this->validate($request, ['filename' => 'regex:/^[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]*$/']);
}
```

This will accept empty filenames; if you want to accept non-empty only change the `*` to `+`.

Answer (score 0):

I checked above solutions but that was not working in my version. My Laravel v. 5.5.

```
 'address' => "required|regex:/^[0-9A-Za-z.\s,'-]*$/",
```